# Downloading MDB (Access) file from IIS

Tags: iis, download, ms-jet-ace

This question might be better asked over on ServerFault, but since this is related to a programming project, I'll ask here.

Simply put, how do I configure IIS to let me download an Access (.MDB) file the same way it lets me download .HTML, .EXE, etc. files?

I've tried taking MDB out of the mime types, changing the extension to .DAT, telling my local directories to treat .MDB files like binary/octet-stream files, yet nothing works.  I still get a "(401) Unauthorized" access.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Figures that as soon as I ask, I figure it out.  I had not given "Everyone" read permission on the file.  Did that and removed the .MDB Application Mapping, and it wored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is purely a server-side issue.  I think different browsers may handle it different ways as well.

How about zipping up the access database and letting users download the zip file?  I'd say that most users out there have the ability to do this.

Comment: Zipping would work, I'll have to see about that in the next version.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. IIS is forbidding download of .mdb files. Here are ref's for your use:

- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29460604/iis-6-wont-serve-mdb-file.aspx
- http://www.windowsreference.com/internet-information-services-iis/fix-for-iis-fails-to-download-access-mdb-file-mime-type/